# Invoke with pointers in VB

Tags: .net, vb.net, pointers

How to invoke this function from XLDownload.dll in VB?

```
DWORD __stdcall QueryTaskInfo(LONG lTaskId, LONG *plStatus, ULONGLONG *pullFileSize, ULONGLONG *pullRecvSize);
```

I've tried to use ByRef ULong and also ByVal IntPtr to invoke but neither works. They both cause PInvokeStackImbalance Error.

Comment: What is the name of the DLL, what have you tried so so far?

Comment: LONG is ByVal Integer, LONG* is ByRef Integer, ULONGLONG* is ByRef Long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<DllImport("XLDownload.dll", CharSet := CharSet.Auto, SetLastError := True, BestFitMapping := False, CallingConvention := CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
Private Shared Function QueryTaskInfo(lTaskId As UInt32, ByRef plStatus As UInt32, ByRef pullFileSize As UInt64, ByRef pullRecvSize As UInt64) As UInt32
End Function
```